# pandas get sheet names contains a keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to combine all sheets that have the string 'BOOKING' in them. I've already looked for such documents, but there aren't any available samples. Can somebody help me? I only know how to read the name of a given sheet.

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'test.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(File,sheet_name = 'JANUARY BOOKING')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
import pandas as pd


file = 'test.xlsx'
keyword = 'BOOKING'

xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(file)
sheet_names = [sheet for sheet in xls_file.sheet_names if keyword.upper() in sheet.upper()]

dfs = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = sheet_names)
df = pd.concat([df.assign(sheet_name=name) for name, df in dfs.items()])

print(df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

> ##### Make sure have `openpyxl` installed in your environment. If don't then use this command `pip install openpyxl`

Comment: It's worth noting that this way also requires `openpyxl` to make `pd.ExcelFile` work

Comment: @Sabil if you don't have that you'll get `ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.`

Comment: I have `openpyxl` installed in env

Comment: @Sabil. This is noted, is there a way to have only specific table header to display

Comment: Could you please add an example of that?

Comment: I just want to display specific columns. e.g 'ID#' , 'Address' , 'Invoice'

Comment: Definitely, you can do something like this `new_df = df[['ID#', 'Address', 'Invoice']]`

Comment: Hi @Sabil, I have a similar question. My excel file contains sheets named as numbers (e.g., 2001, 2002, ...) and alphanumeric (e.g., ABC3001, ABC3002,...). I want to read only the sheets 2001, 2002,... How would you modify your script? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) also accept list of *sheet names* as `sheet_name` argument. So you could use `openpyxl` to parse and filter the sheet names.

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> filename = "your_sheet.xlsx"
>>> wb = load_workbook(filename=filename)
>>> list_of_sheetnames = [sheet for sheet in wb.sheetnames if "BOOKING" in sheet]
>>> df = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name=list_of_sheetnames)
```